# finding bottleneck. Ffmpeg does not utilize 800% on 4core\8threads CPU. Why?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode video's (using x264 codec) on E3-1245 V2 3.40GHz CPU, 32 GB RAM, 2TB 7200RPM disks (with soft Raid 1) debian 6 server

E3-1245 V2 has 4 cores / 8 threads, but ffmpeg can't utilize all 800%, and utilize about 200%  per instance.

I read many other threads, and people always say "Run few ffmpeg process in parallel mode"

But where actually the bottleneck in one ffmpeg instance ? CPU bus / RAM freq. speed ??

```
exec ("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $fullpath . ' -pass 1 -passlogfile    
/var/www/scripts/twopass2.log -refs 1 -threads 0 -vcodec libx264 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb 
-s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -r 24 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -x264opts 
"keyint=48:min-keyint=48:scenecut=0:stats=/var/www/scripts/stats2.log" -b:v 2300k -bf 0 
-profile:v baseline  -mixed-refs 0 -level 30 -maxrate 80M -bufsize 80M  -acodec aac -
async 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts  -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -map 0 -dn -sn -y 
/dev/null');

exec ("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i " . $fullpath . ' -pass 2 -passlogfile 
/var/www/scripts/twopass2.log -refs 1 -threads 0 -vcodec libx264 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb 
-s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -r 24 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -x264opts 
"keyint=48:min-keyint=48:scenecut=0:stats=/var/www/scripts/stats2.log" -b:v 2300k -bf 0 
-profile:v baseline  -mixed-refs 0 -level 30 -maxrate 80M -bufsize 80M  -acodec aac -
async 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts  -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -map 0 -dn -sn -
 flags  -global_header -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10  -
segment_list /dev/null -y ' . $idpath . '2/%5d.ts');
```

I think there is demuxing problem, but not sure.

Also I tried something like this:

```
mkfifo pipe.y4m
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f yuv4mpegpipe -y pipe.y4m
and run
x264 -o dvd1.264 pipe.y4m
```

CPU utilizing a bit better (about 150% ffmpeg and 350% - x264) but also this is not 800% at all.

Any way to speed up encoding ?
And where actually bottleneck there ?

Comment: Do you set number of threads? Hard to tell with so little info. I'd bet on IO. What happen if you run then in parallel?

Comment: Yes. I also tried -thread 0; -threads auto and -threads 8, but ffmpeg  doesn't care. Nothing happened, but it's a problem right now on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

Answer edit:

@user3652819 If your ffmpeg build compiled with pthread support, the -threads option should work. If ffmpeg can't use your CPU power even though you use -threads, that means some of the encoding or decoding algorithms are not parallelizable enough. Let me explain you this parallelisation issue:

Carrying sand with wheelbarrow is a fully parallelizable work. You can use wheelbarrows as much as you want. Putting some people into bus is not a parallelizable work. The people has to get in one by one.

I usually run more ffmpeg instances for handling more files to use my free CPU power.

Old post:

> Some of the codec's algorithm you are using in input or output may not parallelizable enough. What are the input files you are using? Is this problem persists when you use a libx264 encoded file as input?

Comment: This answer should have been a comment (but maybe you didn't have enough reputation points?).

Comment: In input I have h264 (High Profile)  yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2001 kb/s, 50 fps, in MP4 container

Comment: @user3652819 If your ffmpeg build compiled with pthread support, the -threads option should work. If ffmpeg can't use your CPU power even though you use -threads, that means some of the encoding or decoding algorithms are not parallelizable enough. Let me explain you this parallelisation issue:


Carrying sand with wheelbarrow is a fully parallelizable work. You can use wheelbarrows as much as you want.

Putting some people to bus is not a parallelizable work. The people has to get in one by one.

I am running more instances for handling more files to use my free CPU power.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sorry about this. I don't have 50 reps to comment.